# JAVA - Sending data to child process in a loop

Tags: java, process, inputstream, outputstream

I want to send some string to a child process and them, and this send me back in uppercase. The idea is that i put an empty string,both process will stop. 
The first time works all great but the next times the process get stuck in the second time and i need to force close.

Father Code ->

```
public class padre {
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Soy el padre");
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar C:\\Users\\Cristian\\Desktop\\hijo.jar");

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader escritorPadre = new BufferedReader(isr);

        //Leer del hijo
        BufferedReader brHijo = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader brHijoError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
        //EScribir en el hijo
        OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();


        String lineaConsola;
        while((lineaConsola = escritorPadre.readLine()).isEmpty() == false){

            lineaConsola +="\n";
            os.write(lineaConsola.getBytes());
            os.flush();


            String linea;
            while((linea = brHijo.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(linea);
                System.out.println("Atascado en el while del padre");
            }
            while((linea = brHijoError.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(linea);
                System.out.println("Atascado en el while del padre error");
            }

        }






    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Child code ->

```
public class hijo {
public static void main(String[] args){
    InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
    String linea;
    try {
        while(!(linea = br.readLine()).isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Hijo -> " + linea.toUpperCase()+"\n");
            System.out.println("Atascado en el while del hijo");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: **Why** incur the overhead of starting multiple JVMs instead of calling another method in one?

Comment: And you don't need the empty line. Just closing the output stream will produce end of stream at the child process's input stream. You don't need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems here.

- First, in your main loops (both father and son), you are not checking for end-of-file. This means that you can get `null` from the stream reader, and you'll get a `NullPointerException` when you try to access `isEmpty()`.
- Second, you are never passing an empty line to the son process, because as soon as the line you get from `escritorPadre.readLine()` is empty, you get out of the `while` loop. So the son checking for `isEmpty()` is futile. It would be better to close the stream to the son as soon as you exit (you always have to close streams when you finish with them, anyway), and handle the `null` on the son side.
- But most importantly: your loop for reading from the son will always get stuck, because you will only get `null` from the son side on end-of-stream. And you will only get end-of-stream if the son uses `close()` on its output stream (or the son terminates). But if you did use `close()` on the son side, you'll not be able to write to standard output again.

  So your loop just keeps waiting for the son to write something else, and the son is waiting for the father to write something else before it writes something. So the process is in a deadlock.

You could decide that the son should send some special output (an empty line) so you know when to stop reading its output.

But then you have a problem with standard error. After you finish reading from the son's output, you start reading from standard error. So to allow you to leave that loop, you'll also have to print an empty line to standard error after each write to the output, and also add an empty line to the stack trace being printed from every `catch`. Then you'll also have to add a check for empty line in the father's loop reading the son's standard error.

Personally, I think that's not very elegant. But it's doable.

Anyway, to get you started, on the father side you should make sure you close all the streams and check for null on reading. Something like:

```
try {
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar C:\\Users\\Cristian\\Desktop\\hijo.jar");
} catch ( IOException e ) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}

// Use try-with-resources to open all the streams and readers
// so that they will be closed automatically
try (
    BufferedReader escritorPadre = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    //Leer del hijo
    BufferedReader brHijo = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader brHijoError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
    //EScribir en el hijo
    OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();
) {

    String lineaConsola;

    // Read until either end-of-file or empty line
    while((lineaConsola = escritorPadre.readLine()) != null && ! lineaConsola.isEmpty()){

       ... // I ommitted the reading from the son until you decide how you want to arrange it.

    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And in the son, also, make sure to close all the resources or use try-with-resources, and check for both null and empty line:

```
try (
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
){
    while((linea = br.readLine()) != null && ! linea.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("Hijo -> " + linea.toUpperCase()+"\n");
        System.out.println("Atascado en el while del hijo");
        // Decide how you want to handle telling the father that output is done
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```